# How to request a JSON response from C3.ai COVID-19 API's?

Tags: json, python-3.x, xml

I am querying C3.ai API's for analyzing unified COVID-19 data. I see that all the API's return an xml formatted string, by default. Currently, I am converting the format to json using the python library, `xmltodict`. Is there a way I can directly request a JSON response?

Here's the code I am running:

```
import json, requests, xmltodict
url = "https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/fetch/"
request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "include": "id",
        "limit": 1
    }
}
response = requests.post(url=url, json=request_data)
print(response.text)
```

And the corresponding response I get is as follows:

```
<fetchResponse version="2.0">
  <type>
    <module>metadata</module>
    <name>FetchResult</name>
    <bindings>
      <k>T</k>
      <v>
        <type>
          <module>typesys</module>
          <name>ReferenceType</name>
        </type>
        <name>OutbreakLocation</name>
        <mixing>true</mixing>
      </v>
    </bindings>
  </type>
  <objs>
    <k>0</k>
    <v>
      <id>AaenHunze_Drenthe_Netherlands</id>
      <meta>
        <fetchInclude>[id,version,typeIdent]</fetchInclude>
        <fetchType>OutbreakLocation</fetchType>
      </meta>
      <version>262145</version>
      <typeIdent>EP_LOC</typeIdent>
    </v>
  </objs>
  <count>1</count>
  <hasMore>true</hasMore>
</fetchResponse>
```

And I am using the following piece of code to convert the xml to json:

```
fetch_object = xmltodict.parse(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one thing you could try would be to specify a Content Type header with your request.

```
import json, requests, xmltodict
url = "https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/fetch/"
headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "include": "id",
        "limit": 1
    }
}
response = requests.post(url=url, json=request_data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying the open source repo [c3covid19](https://github.com/connor-makowski/c3covid19). You can find the [docs here](https://connor-makowski.github.io/c3covid19/api.html). It is a non-official c3 covid19 data lake connection wrapper for python.

Install

```
pip install c3covid19
```

Run

```
from c3covid19 import c3api

cnx=c3api()

request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "include": "id",
        "limit": 1
    }
}

output=cnx.request(
    data_type='outbreaklocation',
    parameters=request_data,
    api='fetch',
    output_type='objs'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The server returns XML by default. To get a JSON response, you must set the **Accept** request HTTP header to `application/json`. If you send a request in which the *Content-Type* header is set to `application/json` but without specifying a value for *Accept*, you will still get an XML response from the API.

Here is a sample cURL request for an evaluated metric about the number of confirmed deaths in Italy during the month of March 2020 according to the Johns Hopkins University dataset. It can be tested from any shell interface or imported into the Postman app, for example:

```
curl 'https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/evalmetrics' \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{
      "spec": {
          "ids": ["Italy"],
          "expressions":["JHU_ConfirmedDeaths"],
          "interval":"DAY",
          "start":"2020-03-01",
          "end":"2020-03-31"
        }
    }'
```

This returns a JSON object. Here below is the same call as the previous one but without including the *Accept* header. In this case, an XML response is returned:

```
curl 'https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/evalmetrics' \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{
      "spec": {
          "ids": ["Italy"],
          "expressions":["JHU_ConfirmedDeaths"],
          "interval":"DAY",
          "start":"2020-03-01",
          "end":"2020-03-31"
        }
    }'
```